# Error on rendering scripts on pug file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to print a variable on pug file. That variable (scripts) have js code. but I get the following error:

> { Error: ./app/views/cms/index.pug:29:9\n    27| \n    28| \n  > 29|         !{scripts}\n----------------^\n    30| \n    31|     body\n    32|
>   if properties.header.version\n\nunexpected text \"!{scr\"\n    at
>   makeError

**My nodejs code:**

```
// ...
var html = pug.renderFile('./index.pug', {
    scripts: '<script type="text/javascript">console.log("Hello World!");</script>',
    title: 'test',
});
// ...
```

**index.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang=properties.lang)
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")

        title #{title}

        script(src="/jquery.js")
        link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="/styles.css")

        !{scripts}

        style.
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }

            /* safari 9 modals fix */
            .no-scroll {
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 100%;
            }
    body
         div !{content}
```

How do I print `!{scripts}` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with :

```
.
   !{scripts}
```